# Java - Printing a maze using a formatted Stringbuilder

Tags: printing, format, stringbuilder, modulo, maze

I would like to create a maze with a StringBuilder that must have a certain format to match a specific output. I am using the following code to do that, but it shaves off the first row of the output.
The given example is a single string that looks like this:

```
final String EXAMPLE01 = "##############           ## ############ # #       ## # # ##### ## #   #   # ## ### # # # ##   # # # # #### # # # # ##   #     # #### ####### ##           ##############";
```

Here is the code to format the string:

```
private void init(Maze z) {
    /**
     * initializes de.uniwue.gdp.labyrinth.Explorer
     */
    maze = z; //set maze
    pov = POV.SOUTH; //set default point of view to South
    idx = maze.width() + 1; //set default index to (1,1) || starting index

    str = new StringBuilder(); //init empty StringBuilder
    for (int i = 0; i < maze.width() * maze.height(); ++i) {

        if  (str.length() != 0 && (str.length() % maze.width() == 0)){ //use modulo to find linebreaks
            str.append("\n");
        }
        str.append('#'); //set all fields to not explored or wall

    }
    str.setCharAt(idx, ' '); //set starting field to explored
    updateDirections(); //init numMarks & validDirections

}
```

the output looks like this:
[image]

But should look like this:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

for (int i = 0; i < maze.width() * maze.height(); ++i)

Try i++ instead of ++i.

'++' before 'i' increments it prior to evaluation '++' after 'i' increments it after evaluation. In the case the loop may be starting at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: The return value of the increment expression isn't being used in this loop, so changing ++i to i++ will have no effect on the logic.  The loop is starting at 0 in both cases.

Comment: Yes,  I thought the problem was related to the modulo operation. It looks like it is adding a new line twice. I did let it start where the string has a length >0 . But this doesn't work either.